# Nested Dynamic Variables for Dataframes in Loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, dynamic-variables

I have multiple pandas dataframe, with same columns but different values.
Ind I need to run an analysis from values of specific columns.

I have 7 dataframes to work with, but let's suppose I had only two.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 0.5, 0.2],
                   'b': [1,1,0.3], 'c':['A','A','B']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [4, 1, 6],
                   'b': [6.2,0.3,0.3], 'c': ['B','A','A']})
```

I opted to use global variables in a *for* loop.

I created:

- *dflist* > list of original dataframes [df1, df2, ...]
- *sumlist* > future dataframes **names** including summaries ['name1','name2']

Data need to be taken out from df in dflist, elaborated and finally will be passed on sumlist.

To do not get lost, I want my dynamic variables to get names from values in *sumlist*.

Here's where I get stuck. The variables I want to create are based on columns of dataframes df1, df2. However the output for each dynamic variable will contain all values from all columns.

```
dflist= [df1, df2]
sumlist= ['name1', 'name2']

for i in dflist:
    for name in sumlist:
        globals()['var{name}'] = i['c'].to_list()
```

On this dummy example, for some reasons, I get the following error:

```
varname1
NameError: name 'varname1' is not defined
```

In the case of the original dataframe, my list *varname1* will give the following result:

```
['A','A','B','B','B','A']
```

Instead I should have had:

```
varname1 = ['A','A','B']
varname2 = ['B','B','A']
```

What puzzles me is that with the very same code, it "works" (albeit wrongly) in a case while it gives error in the other.

I need to overcome the issue or I will be forced to manually write every single variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, my suggestion would be to use a dictionary instead of using an unsafe `globals` command. So instead of:

```
for i in dflist:
    for name in sumlist:
        globals()['var{name}'] = i['c'].to_list()
```

You should do:

```
d = {}
for i, name in zip(dflist, sumlist):
    d[f'var{name}'] = i['c'].tolist()
```

Notice I am using a `zip` function to iterate the two lists in parallel.

Comment: Thank you. While with 'globals' alone I keep not working, using the dictionary resolved all my problems. And beside I've learned something. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `f` for the F-string.

```
    globals()['var{name}'] = i['c'].to_list()
```

vs

```
    globals()[f'var{name}'] = i['c'].to_list()
```

therefore your global variable is being overwritten and named as `var{name}` instead of `varname1`.

Also, better [use dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1373185/5994041) instead of [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an error in your dummy example because you do not have f before '' for the F-string.

It should be like this:

`globals()[f'var{name}'] = i['c'].to_list()`